# FeedMe Import XML feed with HTML

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme

I'm trying to migrate an existing blog into Craft using the FeedMe plugin. The old blog has an XML RSS feed that I'm importing and for the most part, everything works fine but the content section of the XML element contains HTML tags. When importing these tags are not removed or displayed properly.

Is there a way using the FeedMe plugin (Free or Pro version) to strip these tags or have them display properly?

Answer (score 1):

Probably need a little more information (as in, an example of your feed), but if you're trying to import HTML content in an XML-based feed, you'll want to wrap that with `CDATA`, so its escaped properly.

`<html><![CDATA[<p>This is <b>bold</b></p>]]></html>`